# Create Sheets from list in excel using template

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel template  (//desktop/spellTemplate.xltx) Now I have a worksheet open with a list of names starting at `A2`  and a description at `A3`

```
A2         A3
Imp        does 5 damage
death      does 3 damage
ghost      heals 5 life.
```

The list is quite long and i need to do two things with this list. 
First how can i create a new worksheet (in this workbook) for each of the items in the A2 collumn, with the worksheet named after the item.I
Now when it creates the new worksheet, I want it to use the template i created above.

Then put the name `A2` into the templates cell `A1`  and the description`A3` into the templates cell `C1`.  How can I can do this all automatically for the list of names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your list looks like the following and is on a sheet named Spells:

[image]

---

Try running this code by changing the path to the location of your template file:

```
Sub createSheet()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Spells").Range("A2:A4")

    Dim wks As Worksheet


    For Each cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set wks = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count), Type:="C:\Users\PortlandRunner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\spellTemplate.xltx")
            wks.Name = cell.Value

            wks.Range("A1").Value = cell.Value
            wks.Range("C1").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

The `On Error Resume Next` line will skip sheets that already exist.

---

Resulting sheets created:

[image]

Comment: That worked great! and better then way i was trying!.  Just an FYI for anyone else using this, you will have to change the Range to the range of your list in the `set rng = Sheets("Spells").Range("your values")`  and of course like he said, the address of the template